How can methane be an alkane?
Alkanes are compounds which have single bond between C atoms. If so,how can methane be a alkane if it only has one C atom which makes it impossible for 2 C atoms to exist and form single bond with each other. Please correct me if my definiton of alkanes is wrong or if I am misinterpreting the definition

"Alkanes are compounds which have single bond between C atoms." Not necessary true

Alanine has a single bond between С atoms. So do all other amino acids. So do sugars. So do fats. So does sodium acetate. So does toluene. By now, I believe, you may have started to suspect certain shortcomings in that definition of yours.

Alkanes are acyclic saturated hydrocarbon which means they can exist with all the hands of carbon containing hydrogen atoms and so it would not contain any carbon-carbon multiple bonds (so alkenes and alkynes need to have at least two carbons to fit the criteria). By going through the logic, a single carbon atom can have 4 hydrogen atoms which basically is methane. The general formula for alkane is $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$ and n can be 1 i.e. not needing any carbon-carbon single bond.
